# Is there a keyboard shortcut to view the meaning of a squiggly line in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

It'll be nice if I could view the meaning of a squiggly line without doing a mouse hover.

Comment: There's probably no answer so I guess one has to cycle through the errors (F8). In practice, with good programming practices like consistent naming and experience (e.g. to tell that it's a potential overflow), the errors shouldn't happen so often that it warrants this keyboard shortcut (over cycling through the errors).

By error, I'm referring to both errors (red) and warnings (yellow).

Answer (score 6):

`Ctrl + K, Ctrl + I` - Edit.QuickInfo command.

Comment: Works on my machine.

Answer (score 4):

It's Ctrl-. or Shift-Alt-F10 (View.ShowSmartTag).

I'm surprised that the question hasn't been answered for more than half a year. I've been using C# for a day and already have found it annoying to reach for the mouse every time to add a 'using' statement.

Comment: It's not what I want. Consider void Foo(){Bar();} where Bar() does not exist. There will be a squiggly line under Bar. When the caret is not on the same line as Bar, a mouse-over will produce a "The name 'Bar' does not exist in the current context" pop-up. When the caret is on the same line as Bar, the mouse-over will produce a box, which when clicked produces "Generate method stub for 'Bar' in 'namespace'", which is your solution.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly the answer, but a helpful shortcut I usually use to go through errors without using the mouse is <kbd>F8</kbd>, which cycles through the Error list (errors, warnings, messages)

Comment: This is what I was looking for, at least.